# SASS import utils to all files, but only once

Tags: import, webpack, sass

Is there any way to `@import` some file with universal mixins and keyframes (`utils.scss`) to all another scss files?

```
// main.scss, this file is linked in html: <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.scss">.
@import "home.scss";
@import "about.scss";

// home.scss
@import "utils.scss";
...

// about.scss
@import "utils.scss";
...

// utils.scss
@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

It's ok, everything works, but there is `utils.scss` more times in result file:

```
// Result
@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

When `utils.scss` has 100 kB (with compress) and I have 20 files in which is `utils.scss` imported, there is 1,9 MB redundant code, because there is `utils.scss` 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

Take `utils` out of the individual `.scss` files and put it in the `main.scss` file before the other files.

```
// main.scss
@import "utils";
@import "home.scss";
@import "about.scss";
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: https://github.com/wilsonpage/sass-import-once

When included in a SASS module, sass-import-once will prevent the styles being duplicated if @import is called somewhere else. This is cool because it allows every SASS file to declare its own dependencies. This promotes encapulation and allows modules to standalone if need be.